# HDF4 Errror: Non-Existent Dataset

Tags: python

**Error :**

> File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\SD.py", line 1623,
>   in select
>       raise HDF4Error("select: non-existent dataset")
>
> HDF4Error: select: non-existent dataset

Why this error is there i am not getting and as i am not a programmer so not getting the point where the problem is defined.

```
    if isinstance(name_or_index, type(1)):
        idx = name_or_index
    else:
        try:
            idx = self.nametoindex(name_or_index)
        except HDF4Error:
        raise HDF4Error("select: non-existent dataset")
    id = _C.SDselect(self._id, idx)
    _checkErr('select', id, "cannot execute")
    return SDS(self, id)
```

Comment: After `except HDF4Error:` there should be indent(tab/four spaces). Check that.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with indents(4 character spaces or tab) in python. Python uses indents to identify a block of code instead of any enclosures.
Try running this:

```
if isinstance(name_or_index, type(1)):
    idx = name_or_index
else:
    try:
        idx = self.nametoindex(name_or_index)
    except HDF4Error:
        raise HDF4Error("select: non-existent dataset")
        id = _C.SDselect(self._id, idx)
        _checkErr('select', id, "cannot execute")
        return SDS(self, id)
```

I just put an indent for except statement. Check if it works :)
I corrected all indents too after you said you got error again

Comment: Thank you so much now there is a new error to the same code IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Oh, It's probably because you gave too much indentation before else. If else is a statement so they should be in the same margin check updated answer

Comment: your welcome :). If this solved your question click on the tick sign on the left of my answer so that this question is marked as answered onsite